# What is the best way to simply show the first name, on html page, retrieved from database?

Tags: php, html

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$db = 'blood_db';


$connection = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);

if($connection->connect_error){
    die("Server Error ".$connection->connect_error);
}
else{

    $query = ("SELECT first_name FROM accounts WHERE email_address = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");

    $obj = $connection->query($query);

    echo "Welcome ".$obj->first_name;
```

here it shows a notice, which is "
Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$first_name "
It is returning the object, So how would i extract the first name from it?

```
// printf("Welcome %s",$result->);
echo '<br><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
```

Comment: It says : Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array.

Comment: $obj should be a msqli_result object. See the documentation for how to access the data returned from the query:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: your trying to get records from mysql query executed object . you need to fetch the record using one of method like this $row = $obj->fetch_assoc();
    echo "Welcome ".$row['first_name'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic example would be like this:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
$firstname = "";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_test WHERE email_address = '". $_SESSION['username']. "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Retrieve Firstname
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $firstname = $row["first_name"];
    }
} else {
    echo "No results found!";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h3>Welcome <?php echo $firstname; ?></h3>
    </header>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$conn->close();


?>
```

Comment: What do i need to do if I want to restrict user ,once he/she is logged in, from login page?

Comment: You can use sessions for that. Check out these articles:
[Link 1](http://codingcyber.com/simple-login-script-php-and-mysql-64/)
and [Link 2](https://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/)

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
  $result = $connection->query($query);
  if($result){
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     echo "Welcome ".$row['first_name'];
  }else{
      // check error 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, all these worked. But @Parth you missed a terminator in second line of your code :P . BTW thanks.

Comment: What do i need to do if I want to restrict user ,once he/she is logged in, from login page?

Comment: stroe user id in session once he logged in if user id already is in session than redirect user to user account or user dashb oard

Answer (score 1):

you can try this which select data and add condition if you want to check that data empty or not

```
$obj = $connection->query($query);
if ($obj->num_rows > 0) {

    $row = $obj->fetch_assoc();
    echo "Welcome ".$row['first_name'];
}
```

if you do not want to check data have then use this

```
 $row = $obj->fetch_assoc();
 echo "Welcome ".$row['first_name'];
```

for more information

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: A more accurate way, thumbs up to you!

Comment: What do i need to do if I want to restrict user ,once he/she is logged in, from login page?

Comment: you want to check that user already login or not? if yes then show it?

Comment: just follow this, it it good example 

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_mysql_login.htm

Comment: i just want to check that if user is logged in then restrict him from going back to index page which is login page!

Comment: just check this link which help you lot, and you can use session value and check it